# Links to Backward or Forward a PHP Query result

Tags: php, pagination

I have a ticket support system based on mysql/php, and when i open a ticket i have the result:
viewticket.php?invoice=28756

What code/script can i use to add two links (or buttons) to move forward or backward? (to go to the last or next ticket)